# scanfの変換指定子%dと%uの違いがわからない

Tags: c

**質問**

標準ライブラリscanfの変換指定子%dと%uの違いがわかりません。
違いはあるのでしょうか？
違いがあるのであればどのようなときに違うのかが知りたいです。

---

**manマニュアルの説明**

manマニュアルSCANF(3)によると以下の説明がありました。

> d　符号つきの 10進の整数に対応する。 次のポインターは int へのポインターでなければならない。
> u　符号なしの  10進の整数に対応する。 次のポインターは unsigned int へのポインターでなければならない。

以下のケースの組み合わせで確認してみました。

- 変換指定が`%d`、`%u`
- 変数の型が`int`、`unsigned int`

変数に読み込まれた値に違いが確認できませんでした。
`gcc -Wall`と`clang -Weverything`でコンパイルしたときに、エラーや警告はでていません。

【コメントを受けて追記】`gcc -Wall -pedantic`でコンパイルしたときは警告が出ています。

**コンパイラ**

- clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
- gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0

**コンパイル時の警告**
`gcc -Wall -pedantic`でコンパイルすると次の警告が出ます。

```
q6.c: In function ‘main’:
q6.c:15:19: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned int *’ [-Wformat=]
   15 |     num = scanf("%d", &ui);
      |                  ~^   ~~~
      |                   |   |
      |                   |   unsigned int *
      |                   int *
      |                  %d
q6.c:20:19: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   20 |     num = scanf("%u", &i);
      |                  ~^   ~~
      |                   |   |
      |                   |   int *
      |                   unsigned int *
      |                  %u
```

**確認したコード**

```
int num;
int i;
unsigned int ui;

printf("%s", "int:%d => ");
num = scanf("%d", &i);
printf("i=[%x]\n", i);
printf("num=[%d]\n", num);

printf("%s", "unsigned int:%d => ");
num = scanf("%d", &ui);
printf("ui=[%x]\n", ui);
printf("num=[%d]\n", num);

printf("%s", "int:%u => ");
num = scanf("%u", &i);
printf("i=[%x]\n", i);
printf("num=[%d]\n", num);

printf("%s", "unsigned:int %u => ");
num = scanf("%u", &ui);
printf("ui=[%x]\n", ui);
printf("num=[%d]\n", num);
```

出力結果(-100を入力)

```
int:%d => -100
i=[ffffff9c]
num=[1]
unsigned int:%d => -100
ui=[ffffff9c]
num=[1]
int:%u => -100
i=[ffffff9c]
num=[1]
unsigned:int %u => -100
ui=[ffffff9c]
num=[1]
```

Comment: gccで`-Wall`と共に`-pedantic`オプションも付けたときは警告が出るようになりませんか？

Comment: @raccy gcc -Wall -pedantic`でコンパイルしたときは警告が出ます。本文に警告メッセージを追記しました。コメントありがとうございます。確かにこれは「違い」ですね。実行時の振る舞いの違いについては何かご存じありませんか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C言語の規格書を辿ると

> Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the **strtoul** function with the value 10 for the **base** argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to unsigned integer.

のように書かれていて、`%u`は`strtoul` 相当だそうです。で `strtoul` はというと、`strtol`, `strtoll`, `strtoul`, and `strtoull` で一緒くたに扱われてて、（`unsigned long` であっても）マイナス記号を受け入れるそうです。
なので、[cppreferenceの`strtoul`](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul)などでもそのように説明されています。

結局、`scanf`の`%d`と`%u`、および`strtol`と`strtoul`の違いとは引数に要求する変数が符号付きか符号無しかの差はありますが、**入力文字列の解釈に違いはない**となります。